# post hoc HSD for Repeated measures ANOVA be using statsmodels library (python)

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, anova

I try to do post hoc HSD for my repeated measures data. I use statsmodels.stats.multicomp.MultiComparison, but I am not sure that it dael with the repeated measures issue.

my code:

```
from statsmodels.stats.anova import AnovaRM
import statsmodels.stats.multicomp as mc

aovrm2way = AnovaRM(df, amp, 'subject', within=['cond', 'type'])
res2way = aovrm2way.fit()

print(res2way)


comp = mc.MultiComparison(df[amp], df['cond'])
post_hoc_res = comp.tukeyhsd()
post_hoc_res.summary()
print(post_hoc_res.summary())
```

Is it correct to do this for repeated measures? If not, is there another library that provides an answer to repeated measures post hoc tests?

Comment: I doubt that your use of MultiComparison here is giving you the answer you are looking for. Nowhere in the code do you tell MultiComparison to use the repeated measures model. That said, while I don't think what you did here above is correct, I sadly don't know (yet) how to do it properly, or whether current version of sm is even capable of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you check out the function "pairwise_tests" from the pingouin library
https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.pairwise_tests.html#pingouin.pairwise_tests.

Unlike statsmodels.stats.multicomp, pg.pairwise_tests allows you to specify "the Name of column(s) containing the within-subject factor(s), i.e. the repeated measurements".